# Problem Saving ManytoManyField using ModelForm Django

Tags: django, django-forms, manytomanyfield

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Elements(models.Model):
    element = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.element


class Hero(models.Model):
    added = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10, unique=True)
    element = models.ManyToManyField(Elements, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Elements, Hero


class HeroForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        exclude = [
            'added'
        ]
        widgets = {
            'element': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
        }
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import HeroForm


def home(request):
    form = HeroForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        hero = form.save(commit=False)
        hero.added = request.user
        hero.save()


        form = HeroForm()

    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

whenever I try to manipulate the modelform beforesaving like I've shown above in views.py, element's(manytoamyfield) data automatically set to null. However, if I save the form as it is the element's data saved which is selected by the user.

How can I manipulate form data before saving the form and retain manytomanyfield data as it is ?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `commit=False`, then the `ModelForm` can not save the many-to-many relation, since then the object does not have a primary key.

You can simply alter the instance in the form *before* saving the form:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def home(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = HeroForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.instance.added = request.user
            form.save()  # no commit=False
            form = HeroForm()
    else:
        form = HeroForm()
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

---

> **Note**: In case of a successful POST request, you should make a [**`redirect`**
> [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect)
> to implement the [*Post/Redirect/Get* pattern [wiki]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).
> This avoids that you make the same POST request when the user refreshes the
> browser.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to a view to authenticated users with the
> [**`@login_required`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator).